# Memory requirement

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How much harddrive memory does it take to install ROS?
I'm planning to install it on a Rapsberry Pi and need to know
how big SD-card I need to buy.

Cheers
/L

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52330/memory-requirement/) by [Sjosund](https://answers.ros.org/users/3972/sjosund/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on how many packages you install.

My install uses desktop-full + some extra packages. fuerte, 64-bit and I have 2.9G.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my computer, which is a very fat install:

```
flatlander% du -hs /opt/ros/fuerte
6.8G    /opt/ros/fuerte
```

Of course, that's an Ubuntu install on a 64-bit computer, but it might give you an upper bound.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1